# Maths function bug in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math

I recently used the Math function in NodeJS for an API.

When I try `Math.log(114)` for example the output is `4.7361` instead of `2.0569`.

I don't use any external library.

Comment: `Math.log` returns the natural logarithm (base e). Looks like you wanted `Math.log10` instead

Comment: `Math` is an `Object` of `JavaScript`, not of `node.js`. And `log` (and many others) is a `method` of `Math`.

Answer (score 4):

You're wrong there. `Math.log` is the natural logarithm -- which when called will be `4.73619`. If you're looking for the common logarithm use `Math.log10`. `Math.log10(114) = 2.0569...`.

Comment: Thanks, the atan() function also don't work for example : Math.atan(15) return 1.504 instead of 86,18 do you have any idea ?

Comment: atan works in radians, not in degrees... please check the documentation! https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan

Comment: @Dario... exactly.... if you need to use degree... you need to change the degree angle FIRST to radians.... ie: http://cwestblog.com/2012/11/12/javascript-degree-and-radian-conversion/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Math.log10(114)
```

Comment: Might be helpful to explain the difference.

Comment: Check the other comments above: Math.atan() always expects a value in radiants, not degrees.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong method:

```
Math.log(x)
```

Is always the natural logarithm (with "e" as base)

```
Math.log10(x)
```

Is the logarithm in base 10

You should use the second one if you need to compute a logarithm in the common base, instead of the "standard" natural base.